# Where can I find an academic paper that refers 50 species of trees?

Tags: research

I'm a student in a Translation Post-Graduation in Portugal.

Anyway for one of my classes we're analyzing vocabulary and I am supposed to build a database out of an academic paper, it must have from 30 to 50 terms.

For my theme I chose silviculture and for sub-theme species of trees. But I am having trouble finding a paper that refers from 30 to 50 species of trees. I must find a text from where I am supposed to build and translate the database.

Could you tell me where I can find such text? It must be a pdf. If someone has a big text for me work on I would be very happy.

Thank you so much!

Carlos Barros

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Sorry if I posted on the wrong place, my bad, I didn't know, anyway it must be a pdf for this subject because on a normal environment a technical translator deals with many pdfs.

Comment: Does it have to be a paper? This sounds like something one would find in a textbook or in an encyclopedia. Just scan and OCR the pages.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about 50 trees, you're going to have to do some research here, but USDA's Forest Service does tons of work on trees. Here's a [report of trees in Virginia](https://www.srs.fs.usda.gov/pubs/rb/rb_srs197.pdf) which may suffice.
You may have to poke around their servers to find exactly what you seek.